# SMS Verification code request failed : unknown status code 17006

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

Regarding firebase OTP in flutter, Im stuck with the error :
“SMS Verification code request failed : unknown status code 17006.
Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +9xxxxxxxxxxx, error - The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section” for all phone numbers.
Before it was working good.

Ive enabled ‘Phone number’ as sign in option. Also updated the SHA 1 and SHA 256 certificate fingerprints.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Add test numbers in firebase console and try again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.